# Data structures available in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating my first stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and the problem I am attempting to solve needs some sort of data structure that can hold a string associated to multiple other strings, either a hash, or tree of some sort. However I cannot seem to find any examples of this online. Is there a way to use maps or trees in sql stored procedures, or is it assumed that this sort of heavy lifting by done outside in the code?

To be more specific on the problem, it deals with organizational charts. I have a query that can produce every employee and their immeadiate supervisor, but the output that is wanted by the rest of the team is a result set that has all people reporting below a given individual, but with an extra column for their supervisor below the given person. It might be easier to see than talk about.

For Example:

```
Jim and Billy report to Bob, Paul and April report to Kurt 
Kurt and Ed report to Tim, Laurie and Bob report to George
George reports to Maggie
Maggie and Tim report to Jessica
```

With an input of Jessica, the information I need printed out would look like:

```
Jim reports to Maggie
Billy reports to Maggie
Paul reports to Tim
April reports to Tim
Kurt reports to Tim
Ed reports to Tim
Laurie reports to Maggie
Bob reports to Maggie
George reports to Maggie
Tim reports to Jessica
Maggie reports to Jessica
```

The real problem so far has been when running through the loop, I am going down one level at a time and finding everyone under the new records. This works fine if I just want the immeadiate supervisor, but in order to get that jump up to one level below the input I am needed to store the information some where, and I don't know what kind of structures would be supported within SQL for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a tree example:

```
--recursive CTE tree example
DECLARE @Contacts table (id int, first_name varchar(10), reports_to_id int)
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (1,'Jerome', NULL )  -- tree is as follows:
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (2,'Joe'   ,'1')     --                      1-Jerome
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (3,'Paul'  ,'2')     --                     /        \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (4,'Jack'  ,'3')     --              2-Joe           9-Bill
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (5,'Daniel','3')     --            /       \              \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (6,'David' ,'2')     --     3-Paul          6-David       10-Sam
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (7,'Ian'   ,'6')     --    /      \            /    \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (8,'Helen' ,'6')     -- 4-Jack  5-Daniel   7-Ian    8-Helen
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (9,'Bill ' ,'1')     --
INSERT @Contacts VALUES (10,'Sam'  ,'9')     --

DECLARE @Root_id  int

--get complete tree---------------------------------------------------
SET @Root_id=null
PRINT '@Root_id='+COALESCE(''''+CONVERT(varchar(5),@Root_id)+'''','null')
;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.first_name, c.reports_to_id, c.reports_to_id as Manager_id, cc.first_name AS Manager_first_name, 1 AS LevelOf
        FROM @Contacts                  c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Contacts  cc ON c.reports_to_id=cc.id
        WHERE c.id=@Root_id OR (@Root_id IS NULL AND c.reports_to_id IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.id, s.first_name, s.reports_to_id, t.id, t.first_name, t.LevelOf+1
        FROM StaffTree            t
            INNER JOIN @Contacts  s ON t.id=s.reports_to_id
    WHERE s.reports_to_id=@Root_id OR @Root_id IS NULL OR t.LevelOf>1
)
SELECT * FROM StaffTree ORDER BY LevelOf,first_name


--get 2 and all below---------------------------------------------------
SET @Root_id=2
PRINT '@Root_id='+COALESCE(''''+CONVERT(varchar(5),@Root_id)+'''','null')
;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.first_name, c.reports_to_id, c.reports_to_id as Manager_id, cc.first_name AS Manager_first_name, 1 AS LevelOf
        FROM @Contacts                  c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Contacts  cc ON c.reports_to_id=cc.id
        WHERE c.id=@Root_id OR (@Root_id IS NULL AND c.reports_to_id IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.id, s.first_name, s.reports_to_id, t.id, t.first_name, t.LevelOf+1
        FROM StaffTree            t
            INNER JOIN @Contacts  s ON t.id=s.reports_to_id
    WHERE s.reports_to_id=@Root_id OR @Root_id IS NULL OR t.LevelOf>1
)
SELECT * FROM StaffTree ORDER BY LevelOf,first_name

--get 6 and all below---------------------------------------------------
SET @Root_id=6
PRINT '@Root_id='+COALESCE(''''+CONVERT(varchar(5),@Root_id)+'''','null')
;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.first_name, c.reports_to_id, c.reports_to_id as Manager_id, cc.first_name AS Manager_first_name, 1 AS LevelOf
        FROM @Contacts                  c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Contacts  cc ON c.reports_to_id=cc.id
        WHERE c.id=@Root_id OR (@Root_id IS NULL AND c.reports_to_id IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.id, s.first_name, s.reports_to_id, t.id, t.first_name, t.LevelOf+1
        FROM StaffTree            t
            INNER JOIN @Contacts  s ON t.id=s.reports_to_id
    WHERE s.reports_to_id=@Root_id OR @Root_id IS NULL OR t.LevelOf>1
)
SELECT * FROM StaffTree ORDER BY LevelOf,first_name
```

OUTPUT:

```
@Root_id=null
id          first_name reports_to_id Manager_id  Manager_first_name LevelOf
----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- ------------------ -----------
1           Jerome     NULL          NULL        NULL               1
9           Bill       1             1           Jerome             2
2           Joe        1             1           Jerome             2
6           David      2             2           Joe                3
3           Paul       2             2           Joe                3
10          Sam        9             9           Bill               3
5           Daniel     3             3           Paul               4
8           Helen      6             6           David              4
7           Ian        6             6           David              4
4           Jack       3             3           Paul               4

(10 row(s) affected)

@Root_id='2'
id          first_name reports_to_id Manager_id  Manager_first_name LevelOf
----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- ------------------ -----------
2           Joe        1             1           Jerome             1
6           David      2             2           Joe                2
3           Paul       2             2           Joe                2
5           Daniel     3             3           Paul               3
8           Helen      6             6           David              3
7           Ian        6             6           David              3
4           Jack       3             3           Paul               3

(7 row(s) affected)

@Root_id='6'
id          first_name reports_to_id Manager_id  Manager_first_name LevelOf
----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- ------------------ -----------
6           David      2             2           Joe                1
8           Helen      6             6           David              2
7           Ian        6             6           David              2

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1 for an actual database implementation, I was hoping that there was actually built in data structures rather than having to put the code in to create your own using temp tables, but glad at least to get a definitive answer on that.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use recursion in order to pull info you want (use CTE).

Table structure is simple:

```
ID
Name
SupervisorID
```

Let me know if you need help with CTE.